# Do home deliveries of food in the USA have "anti-tampering stickers" on them?

Tags: food-and-drink, restaurants

I've never ordered home food where I live, and certainly not in the USA. One thing that truly worries me is the "trust factor"; not only do I have to trust the restaurant's personnel to not spit in my food or otherwise soil it, but I ***also*** have to trust the person delivering it, who is more than likely to not exactly love his job/life, and might very well do something to my food out of spite, especially if they decide they don't like me for whatever reason.

An extremely cheap and elegant solution would be for the food place to put a kind of cheap but effective "custom sticker" on the food package, so that I can at least be sure that it has not been opened between it leaving the food place and arriving at my door. It might say the restaurant's name and logo with a small text:

> IF SEAL HAS BEEN BROKEN, DO NOT EAT, AND CONTACT US ASAP!

This would cost them virtually nothing extra, yet give me a lot of peace of mind. It also is in line with numerous other such "safety measures" in place today all throughout society, so it wouldn't be an outlandish thing to suggest or do.

This would be especially suitable for pizza cartons, but I've never seen that done in any movie or anything, so I'm worried that it might not be done. It really is a major reason why I don't want to order pizza to my home; just the idea of the delivery person opening it and spitting on it (in a way which isn't obvious to the customer) makes me feel uneasy.

Is this already done? If so, is it *consistently* done? Or only by a few major chains?

Comment: No, they don't, and they'd be pointless anyway because it's often the delivery person who packs your food.  Also, this has nothing to do with travel.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s not travel-related

Comment: @Yuito Dahlager Taking conspiracy theory to the next level, how would you be sure that a delivery person hadn’t broken and then replaced the seal? There could be collusion between the restaurant/kitchen/delivery staff. Just carry on not ordering delivery food and you’ve no need to worry.

Comment: What you think is "virtually nothing" could actually work out to be a significant part of the food's price. Even when you order stickers by the thousands, they costs something, but I suspect that a much larger portion, would be the extra time the restaurant staff has to spend on each piece. And then they would also get extra expenses dealing with all the cases of the sticker being accidentally broken (I guess that will be more cases than actual tampering).

Comment: I drive for Uber Eats. My earnings are directly linked to the speed with which I can complete a delivery, and I try to be professional. If you make my life easy by meeting me at the kerb I'll love you, and mark you up. Insist I walk 300m up a steep hill, or climb a dozen flights of stairs, I'll mark you down, but I won't ever waste my time mucking with your food - it would cost me too much in lost time and earnings

Answer (score 1):

No. This is not generally done. The containers for delivery food will vary depending on the restaurant and type of food, but they are generally boxes and cartons that are not regularly sealed, let alone with tamper-evident seals (there's sometimes a piece of ordinary tape or a staple to keep a box or bag closed). I can't guarantee that nobody does what you propose, but it's not at all common.

Food delivery workers have no particular reason to do anything to your food; they've likely never even met you, so they'd have no reason to decide they dislike you. Don't do anything egregious (make the delivery driver wait 20 minutes or leave a horrible tip), and the driver will have no cause to dislike you, if that's your concern.

Millions of people order food delivery at least occasionally, and it largely goes without incident.